# Atribuir um arttigo em mais de uma categoria php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho que inserir um cadastro no banco de dados atribuído á mais de uma categoria , como poderia fazer isso ? No caso iria aparecer as opções de categoria disponíveis no meu banco  e eu iria selecionar elas com um checkbox

Comment: Não seria o contrario, um artigo ter várias categorias? normalmente se cria uma tabela associativa quem tem o id do artigo e da categoria, para pegas as descrições utilize joins no sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso suas tabelas no banco devem ter mais ou menos essas estrutura:

```
|--------artigo----------|  
|id - titulo - nome - etc|  
|------------------------|  

|---categoria---|  
|id - nome - etc|  
|---------------|  

|-------artigo_categoria------|  
|id - id_artigo - id_categoria|  
|-----------------------------|
```

Com isso você consegue que um artigo tenha mais de uma categoria.
Quando for fazer `select` basta usar um `inner join` para associar.

```
select * from artigo
inner join artigo_categoria on (artigo.id = artigo_categoria.id_artigo)
inner join categoria on (artigo_categoria.id_categoria = categoria.id)
```